# Create context Menu entry for all websites excluding some

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox add-on with the Addon SDK which I would like to contain a context-menu entry for images on all websites except Google images, for which I will add a different context-menu entry.

```
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");

cm.Item({
  label: "LABEL",
  context: [
    cm.URLContext(["*.images.google.*"]),
    cm.SelectorContext("img")
  ],
  contentScript: googleContentScript ,
  onMessage: ...
});

cm.Item({
  label: "LABEL",
  context: [
     cm.URLContext(["*"]),
     cm.SelectorContext("img")
  ],
  contentScript: otherContentScript ,
  onMessage: ...
});
```

For the first URLContext I would like to catch all Google images regardless of TLD (.com , .co.uk ...).
And for the second one I would like to be able to have the URLContext apply to all URLs that are not in the first.

Obviously this is not what is currently happening.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does URLContext take RegEx? If it does let me know and I can help you

Comment: @Noitidart, [it does support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#URLContext%28matchPattern%29) somewhat limited [full-match regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern#Regular_Expressions). But if you're so eager to help why haven't you looked into the docs yourself?

Comment: I'm racking my brains with this stuff right __[here](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2006/10/01/manipulating-taskbar-buttons/comment-page-2/#comment-467865)__. If I get that done that will help thousands of more people so I'm more motivated there :P haha. I didnt get into it too much but my regex failed so gave up promptly haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [match patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#URLContext%28matchPattern%29) for `URLSelector` are somewhat limited and hard to deal with when it comes to *negative* patterns.

You have to reasonable options:

- You an implement `self.on("context", function() ...)` in your content script. Returning `false` will make the menu item not show up.

> A special event named "context" is emitted in your content scripts whenever the context menu is about to be shown. If you register a listener function for this event and it returns true, the menu item associated with the listener's content script is shown in the menu.

- If you're targeting Firefox 29+, then using a [`PredicateContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#PredicateContext%28predicateFunction%29) might be easier (to maintain) and also yield better performance (as it does not need to initiate and  go through the content script).

Comment: thanks :) i kind of half assed tried to cover for you but failed :P

Comment: @nmaier, so you're saying I should not use URLContext and instead check for Google domains in the Google content script in the `self.on("context", function() ...)` function, returning true for Google pages and false otherwise. While the other content script would be the same but return opposite values?

Comment: If the Google pattern can be easily converted to a valid `URLContext`, then I'd use that before it is more efficient. Right now it contains multiple wild-cards, so it is not exactly valid (a regex would work). Yes to the "Other" pattern: Use `self.on("context", ...)` or `PredicateContext`